# How to pass values to a datagridview?

Tags: .net, winforms, linq, entity-framework, datagridview

Well i am joining two tables of a DataSet and then want to show these values in a single Datagridview.... the problem i am facing is that i am unable to pass the collected values to the Datagridview. The code to join the two tables is given below, need ur help to show these values in the form of datagridview.

```
var results = from a in myDatabaseDataSet.FinishedStockProducts
                     join am in myDatabaseDataSet.TransferNotes on a.FinishedStockProductId equals am.TransferNoteId
                     select new
                     {
                         Name = a.Name,
                         CostRate = a.CostRate,
                         CostValue= a.CostValue,
                         OpeningBalance = am.OpeningBalance,
                         ClosingBalance = am.ClosingBalance,
                         Total = am.Total
                     };
```

Comment: Can you post what is the error you are getting?

Comment: You need to set the DataSource of the gridview to your var results

Comment: The answer given below worked for me... but that is not the most flexible one... m in search of a better solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = Results.Tolist();
```

Use Simple this Line to Display Value in DataGridview.

Comment: Just want to know, is there a better way to do the joining and then linking it to the DataGridView as a data source...?